# Non-orientable 6-manifold with certain Betti numbers

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

My question is about an aside that came about when answering the following question [Closed oriented manifold with middle Betti is one with odd degree.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944505/closed-oriented-manifold-with-middle-betti-is-one-with-odd-degree).

Is there any sequence $(1,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,0)$ $a_i \geq 0$ integers which cannot be the Betti number sequence of a compact non-orientable $6$-manifold?

I can think of examples (from products of real projective spaces, non-orientable surfaces etc.) with $(1,0,0,0,0,0)$, $(1,1,1,1,1,1,0)$, $(1,0,1,0,0,0,0)$, $(1,1,0,0,0,0)$ , $(1,0,0,0,1,0,0)$ then connect sum gives almost every possibility. But for some sequences I not able to think of an example, for example $(1,0,0,1,0,0,0)$.

Sorry if this is a naïve question I haven't thought about non-orientable manifolds for a long time. My expectation is that probably everything can be realised but I don't know enough examples (perhaps fibre bundles are enough to give everything)?

Comment: This talk mentions exactly which Betti numbers are realizable by non orientable manifolds https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLEWKDtCPTU . In short, there are two obvious conditions one must satisfy and if you do you are realized.

Comment: Thanks, do you have reference to these conditions in print?

Comment: @ConnorMalin:  Can you summarize those conditions?  I thought I was just writing an answer saying "there are no restrictions"  (Except the obvious $a_0 = 1$ and $a_6 = 0$.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito In addition to what you say, in the odd dimensional case (so not this one), you must have the alternating sum of the betti numbers equal to 0

Comment: Coming from the fact that the Euler characteristic can be calculated from homology with any field coefficients.

Comment: I answered the question you asked, finding an example with that sequence.  However, I no longer believe that connect summing these things will give everything, due to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187413/computing-the-homology-and-cohomology-of-connected-sum.  The point is that connecting summing two non-orientable manifolds $M,N$ creates rational cohomology in degree $\dim M - 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I claim that in every even dimension, any sequence of rational Betti numbers can occur.
As you noted, in each dimension $k$, it's sufficient to find examples $N^k_m$ with $0 < m < k$ with $H^\ast(N^k_m;\mathbb{Q})\cong H^\ast(S^m;\mathbb{Q})$, for then connect summing gives everything.  **EDIT**:  This is wrong.  connect summing two non-orientable manifolds adds rational cohomology in degree $k-1$.  **End Edit**

Now, if $m$ is even, one can simply use $N^k_m = S^m\times \mathbb{R}P^{k-m}$.  (Since $m$ and $k$ are both even, so is $k-m$, and $\mathbb{R}P^{even}$ has the rational cohomology of a point.)

So, we need only handle the case where $m$ is odd.  Set $n:=k-m$, which is also odd since $k$ is even and $m$ is odd.  Consider the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action on $S^m \times S^n$ with $-1\ast(x,y) = (-x, r(y))$ where $r:S^n\rightarrow S^n$ is any reflection in a hyperplane.

This action is free since it is free on the first factor.  Call the resulting quotient manifold $M$.  I claim that $N^k_m = M$ works.

Because $m$ is odd, the antipodal map is orientation preserving.  Since $r$ reverses orientation, it follows that the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action reverses orientation.  In particular, $M$ is non-orientable.

I claim that $H^\ast(M;\mathbb{Q}) \cong H^\ast(S^m;\mathbb{Q})$.  To this this, first note that since $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is finite, we have a [transfer homomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452366/is-there-a-definition-of-the-transfer-homomorphism-between-cohomology-of-cover) $f:H^\ast(M;\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H^\ast(S^m\times S^n;\mathbb{Q})$ for which the composition $f\circ \pi^\ast$ is multiplication by $2$ (which is an isomorphism with $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients).  In particular, $\pi^\ast$ is an injection, so the rational Betti numbers of $M$ are zero except possibly in degrees $0,m,n,m+n$.  Further, the Betti numbers are $a_0, a_m, a_n, a_{m+n}$ are all bounded by $1$ (except when $m = n$, in which case $a_{m}$ is bounded by $2$).

Now the antipodal action on $S^m$ is free with quotient $\mathbb{R}P^m$.  The associated bundle construction now shows that $M$ is the total space of an $S^n$ bundle over $\mathbb{R}P^m$.  Pulling back this bundle along the double cover $S^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^m$, we obtain a commutative diagram $$\begin{array} AS^n & \longrightarrow & S^n \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
S^m\times S^n & \longrightarrow & M\\
\downarrow &  & \downarrow \\
S^m & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{R}P^m
\end{array}$$

The induced map on cohomolgoy $H^m(\mathbb{R}P^m;\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H^m(S^m;\mathbb{Q}))\rightarrow H^m(S^m\times S^n;\mathbb{Q})$ is easily seen to be non-trivial.  It follows from commutativity that $H^m(\mathbb{R}P^m;\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H^m(M;\mathbb{Q})$ must be non-zero, so $H^m(M;\mathbb{Q})$ is non-trivial.

In addition, if $H^n(M;\mathbb{Q}) \neq 0$ (or $H^m(M;\mathbb{Q})$ has dimension $2$ when $m=n$), then we have a problem:  If $x\in H^m(M;\mathbb{Q})$ is non-zero and $y\in H^n(M;\mathbb{Q})$ is non-zero (and $x$ and $y$ are independent if $m = n$), then $\pi^\ast(xy) = \pi^\ast(x)\pi^\ast(y)\neq 0$, which implies $H^{m+n}(M;\mathbb{Q}) = 0$.  Since we already know $M$ is non-orientable, this is absurd.  Thus, we conclude that $H^\ast(M;\mathbb{Q})\cong H^\ast(S^m;\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: To clarify after my edit, I still think that in each even dimension $k$ and for any $0 < m < k$, there is a $k$-manifold $M$ with $H^\ast(M;\mathbb{Q})\cong H^\ast(S^m;\mathbb{Q})$.  I no longer believe that finding these examples are enough to generate all combinations of Betti numbers through connect summing them.

Comment: Do you mean "which implies $H^{m+n}(M; \mathbb{Q}) \neq 0$" in the final paragraph?

Comment: @Michael:  Yes.  I am not sure editting is worth bumping this post.